# Mandar Session do carrinho por email com PHPmailer

Tags: php, array, session, phpmailer

Tenho esse código que mostra o resultados do itens que tem no carrinho

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once "functions/product.php";
    require_once "functions/cart.php";

    $pdoConnection = require_once "connection.php";

    if(isset($_GET['acao']) && in_array($_GET['acao'], array('add', 'del', 'up'))) {

        if($_GET['acao'] == 'add' && isset($_GET['id']) && preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_GET['id'])){ 
            addCart($_GET['id'], 1);            
        }

        if($_GET['acao'] == 'del' && isset($_GET['id']) && preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_GET['id'])){ 
            deleteCart($_GET['id']);
        }

        if($_GET['acao'] == 'limpar'){ 
            limpacart($_GET['id'], 1);
        }

        if($_GET['acao'] == 'up'){ 
            if(isset($_POST['prod']) && is_array($_POST['prod'])){ 
                foreach($_POST['prod'] as $id => $qtd){
                        updateCart($id, $qtd);
                }
            }
        } 
        header('location: carrinho.php');
    }

    $resultsCarts = getContentCart($pdoConnection);
    $totalCarts  = getTotalCart($pdoConnection);


?>
```

Como eu poderia enviar os itens por email com o PHPMailer?

```
// Instância do objeto PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SetLanguage("br");
$mail->Body = utf8_decode($body);

// Configura para envio de e-mails usando SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

// Servidor SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.xxx.com.br';

// Usar autenticação SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

// Usuário da conta
$mail->Username = 'xxx@xx.com.br';

// Senha da conta
$mail->Password = 'xxx@';

// Tipo de encriptação que será usado na conexão SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

// Porta do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = 465;

// Informa se vamos enviar mensagens usando HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

// Email do Remetente
$mail->From = 'xx@xx.com.br';

// Nome do Remetente
$mail->FromName = $email_cart;

// Endereço do e-mail do destinatário
$mail->addAddress('xx@xx.com.br');

// Assunto do e-mail
$mail->Subject = 'xxxxx';

// Mensagem que vai no corpo do e-mail
$mail->Body = ' AQUI OS INTENS DO CARRINHO';
```

saída

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1906 [name] => GLVC 3100 [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1907 [name] => HDRC 3153 [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2385 [name] => HDN 01 [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 2390 [name] => HDN 06 [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 2392 [name] => HDN 08 [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 2421 [name] => Santa Ceia [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 2422 [name] => Tartaruga [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 2423 [name] => Tijolo [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 2451 [name] => Argamassa Refrataria [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 2452 [name] => Massa Refrataria em saca [price] => [quantity] => 1 [subtotal] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: Bem vindo marelevou! Companheiro, coloque um exemplo da saída dos resultados da busca do carrinho. Em vista só falta você criar a mensagem do seu e-mail, seria apenas escrita ou HTML? ... Para editar a pergunta e adicionar esses detalhes, clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/325185/edit)  abaixo da sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado @rbz sim só preciso criar um html com os itens do carrinho, como faria? editei a pergunta com a saída

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Montando uma tabela, exemplo simples:

```
# gera cabeçalho
$conteudo = '<table><tr><th>Nome</th><th>Preço</th><th>Qtd</th></tr>';
# gera conteúdo
foreach($array as $v) {
    $conteudo .= "<tr>";
    $conteudo .= "<td>$v['name']</td>";
    $conteudo .= "<td>$v['price']</td>";
    $conteudo .= "<td>$v['quantity']</td>";
    $conteudo .= "</tr>";
}
# fecha a table
$conteudo .= '</table>';

# inclui o conteúdo
$mail->Body = $conteudo;
```

Comment: está retornando esse erro the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: O envio do e-mail está funcionando normalmente? Da forma que fez `$mail->Body = ' AQUI OS INTENS DO CARRINHO';` está recebendo, correto?

Comment: era a concatenação o problema agora funcionou

Comment: Vi que você alterou minha resposta, mas foi um exemplo que usei `$array` ao invés de `$resultsCarts`, pois não sabia se iria usar também o outro `$totalCarts`. É só montar da forma que achar melhor agora, como se tivesse montando uma página. Só lembre que para utilizar estilo, terá que usar inline.